# Upcoming birthdays with MongoEngine

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

Any idea how can I find the next upcoming birthdays considering this code (based on Python/Mongoengine)

```
class User(mongoengine.Document):
  (...)
  birthday = DateTimeField()
```

I know how to do it in plain SQL, but I have no idea how to do this query with this language.

Answer (score 1):

There could be some benefit to save something like:

```
class User(mongoengine.Document):
  birthdate = DateTimeField()
  birth_month = IntegerField()
  birth_day = IntegerField()
```

then to query, everyone with bithrdays this month or next month

```
current_month = datetime.now().month
current_day = datetime.now().day
next_month = (datetime.date.today() +
              dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta(months=1)).month

User.object.filter(Q(birth_month=current_month, birth_day__gte=current_day) |
                    Q(birth_month=next_month)).order_by('birthday')
```

The above should get all the users who have birthday from today until next the end of next month.  Started to write a solution but failed!, this problem seems deceptively hard, hopefully someone has a lot cleaner solution